# Laravel Auth return different data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-authentication

Sorry, anyone please help me. 
I use Laravel 5.4. I just wanna echo auth()-user()->role in view, but the result is different when I echo auth()->user()->role in controller. This is the code.

```
if(!empty(auth()->user())){
   echo auth()->user()->role;
}
```

[result from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1ix3.png)

```
<li class="">
   <a href="#withdraw" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
     <i class="material-icons">archive</i>
     Withdraw {{auth()->user()->role}}
     <div class="ripple-container"></div>
   </a>
</li>
```

[result from view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U5ah.png)

The correct data is 3. Does anyone know the problem? I've tried to clear cache, but no changes. Thanks

Comment: please add your code in this question , not any image link

Comment: what you see when you see the user id ? example: dd(auth()->user()->id); check this in controller and view also

Comment: the id is correct, not different

Comment: role is attribute or method in your model ?

Comment: attribute, role is name of column in user table